# How to solve 3x3 matrix game graphically?

Tags: game-theory

The matrix I have is

```
0   4   6

5   7   4

9   6   3
```

The question tells me to solve it 'graphically'. But there is no dominance among the actions, so I can't reduce it to a 2 x n or m x 2 matrix. I tried to equate the expected payoffs, but didn't get matching lower and upper values. The only method that seems viable to proceed with is by using LPP. Am I correct? Is there any way I can solve this graphically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by myself.

A mixed strategy for player 2, (1/2, 0, 1/2) is letting my combination weakly dominate the 2nd column. Then I can convert it to a 3 x 2 matrix that can be easily solved graphically.